# Struggling with functional dependency practice questions

Tags: database, relational-database, database-normalization, functional-dependencies, bcnf

I'm going over some practice questions.

```
F={ B→E, C→B, CD→E, ABE→C}
```

I tried to make a canonical cover -

```
Fc ={ B→E, C→B, D→E, AB→C}
```

Then finding candidate keys -

```
ADB, ADC
```

Is R in BCNF? I thought it isn't in BCNF if I do not do lossless and dependency preserving decomposition, so I decomposed so:

```
R1=(B,E) BCNF
R2=(C,B) BCNF
R3=(D,E) BCNF
R4=(A,B,C) BCNF
R5=(A,D,B) NF3
```

Alongside every decomposition I wrote what state I think it's in. Lastly I need to decompose R so that all relations are in BCNF, so that would mean decomposing R5 so that it's in BCNF, but I don't how to do that since I can't find D or A using functional dependencies.

Comment: A "relation" is a table. A "functional dependency", written in the form x->y, makes a statement about a relation value or variable. When a relation is in a NF it's also in all the lower NFs.

Comment: What is your (1 specific researched non-duplicate) question? PS What does "find D or A using functional dependencies" (or "find D or A using relations") mean? Why can't you "find"? For the subgoal you are stuck on state exactly what you are starting wiht & the process you are following & the steps you took & what step you are 1st stuck on & why how you are stuck.

Comment: (In a comment to Renzo's answer, the o.p. asks to explain my "some misunderstandings".) The workings here show a canonical cover including `{..., D→E, ...}`. Not only is this not in the c.c.; it doesn't even hold. FD `CD→E` is redundant/extraneous. For completeness, the q should list all the attributes in the relation. (Renzo's answer makes an explicit assumption.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a relation `R(A, B, C, D, E)` and a cover of its functional dependencies `F = { B→E, C→B, CD→E, ABE→C }`, in the canonical cover the dependency `D→E` should be eliminated (it cannot be derived in any way). In `CD→E` the attribute `E` is extraneous, since `C+ = { CBE }`,
and the dependency `C→E`is redundant, since we have already `C→B` and `B→E`.

So a canonical cover is:

```
Fc={B→E, C→B, AB→C}
```

Since `D` does not appear in any dependency of `Fc`, it must be present in any candidate key (and you have correctly identified the only candidate keys, `{ABD, ADC}`).

So we have that the relation is not in BCNF (each dependency in the canonical cover has a determinant which is not a superkey).

You can decompose the relation in several ways in BNCF, depending on
which order you consider the dependencies, but those decompositions are not dependency preserving. For instance, if you
decompose R in:

```
R1 {A, C, D}
R2 {B, E}
R3 {B, C}
```

the dependency `AB→C` is lost. In particular, in this case does not exists a decomposition in BCNF such that all the original dependencies are preserved.

A 3NF decomposition that maintain both data and dependencies
is the following:

```
R1 {A, B, C}
R2 {B, E}
R4 {A, C, D}
```

Comment: this is posed as an exercise, and there are already many similar q's on Stackoverflow. The attempted workings from the questioner already show some misunderstandings. Then giving a model answer is adding nothing to Stackoverflow, and is not encouraging the questioner to learn/think critically.

Comment: could u explain some misunderstandings?